# Layout_Below is not getting executed properly in relativelayout

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have the following xml code. The imagebutton is not getting aligned below the textView with a margin of 5dp. I think I am making a mistake in understanding the various layout parameters. The relativelayout is a childview of a linearlayout having few other views.

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40">

        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
            android:id="@+id/amain_dp"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amain_tv_currentsteps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/amain_ib_whatsapp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/amain_tv_currentsteps"
            android:background="@drawable/whatsapp_icon"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the output I am getting:

[image]

EDIT: The code works properly if `layout_weight` parameter is removed and fixed `layout_height` parameter is provided. But would like to understand why the above code fails because of the `layout_weight`

EDIT: Complete xml code:

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="in.jiyofit.basic_app.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amain_tv_target"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40">

        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
            android:id="@+id/amain_dp"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amain_tv_currentsteps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/amain_ib_whatsapp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/amain_tv_currentsteps"
            android:background="@drawable/whatsapp_icon"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/amain_fl_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The layout looks fine on my end. Did you take the screenshot in layout editor of Android Studio?

Comment: it is from my cell phone. Add another view with a `layout_weight` that may be the cause.

Comment: my answer should work

Comment: Are you using `Instant Run`? If yes, uninstall the app and retry.

Comment: what is this issue with `Instant Run`?

Comment: I tried reinstalling the app, it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Although, its a long shot but, can you try replacing your `DonutProgress` view with an `ImageView` and see the results then. You should be able to see the result in layout editor only.

Comment: @Shaishav, it didn't work. The icon is still at the top

Comment: Hey @suku I was trying your problem as it intrigued me a lot. I noticed that in your `ImageButton` you have used the `background` property. If you need to do that only, you can switch to `ImageView` and `src` property instead of `background`. I'm saying this because my layout varied a bit when I did the change. Try it.

Comment: Yes I can use image view instead of image button. But if I use source then then the image may get "cropped" but by using background, the image is made to fit. But I don't think that has any effect on the layout-below. Please see my edit

Comment: Thanks for your persistence :)

Comment: Alright. Can you share the code for the immediate parent of the above `RelativeLayout` (I'd prefer the entire layout file but, your call). I'm still trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Shaishav, added the entire layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your layout has following scheme:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView/>
        <RelativeLayout/>
        <FrameLayout/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In the above hierarchy, all `LinearLayout` children have a layout weight property set which basically ask the parent to provide `(layout_weight/weightSum) * parentHeight()` space to it within the parent and the `LinearLayout` itself has a `lauout_height` set to `wrap_content` which basically asks the children to tell their heights so `LinearLayout` itself can scale accordingly. This is a circular dependency and hence the layout tool is having trouble figuring out the position.

In this scenario you have two option:

1 - Remove the `ScrollView` and set `Linearlayout's` height to `match_parent`. Every child element of the layout will stretch accordingly to take up screen space properly. Your layout will look like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="80">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amain_tv_target"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40">

        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
            android:id="@+id/amain_dp"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amain_tv_currentsteps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/amain_ib_whatsapp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/amain_tv_currentsteps"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/amain_fl_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2 - Since you have a `ScrollView` in place, you can provide absolute height to each child of `LinearLayout` and let the `LinearLayout` height be `wrap_content`. The `ScrollView` will adequately scale your layout accordingly for different screens. Your layout may look something like this:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="80">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amain_tv_target"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp">

            <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
                android:id="@+id/amain_dp"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amain_tv_currentsteps"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/amain_ib_whatsapp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/amain_tv_currentsteps"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/amain_fl_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Just as a rule of thumb, make sure that the height/width of your `LinearLayout` if determinable before you supply `layout_weight` property to its children. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think `linear_layout` has to be `wrap_content` inside scroll view. So the 2nd solution cannot be used if `layout_weight` is used.

Comment: @suku totally your call

Answer (score 0):

You need to use +
like this:

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/amain_tv_currentsteps"
```

Comment: `+` is needed only when your are using the name of the view for the first time (either while creation or during referencing).

Comment: For me it did the job

Comment: What job? I'm saying its not required to have a `+`. It won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

in you top  `RelativeLayout` give a size to it  0dp makes the issue because it (that rel has 0 height and )  your image view goes below it.

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: It is probably a child to a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @Charuka, I need to use `layout_weight`

Comment: @Shaishav, yes the relative layout is a child to a linearlayout having other views

Comment: but you also give a hard code height as 0 dp thats where the issue comes

Comment: @Charuka What value do you usually use with layout weight? As far as i remember `0dp` is the recommended value.

Comment: @Charuka ImaageButton is below the textView and not the Circle `donutProgress`. So it should not be a problem

Comment: 0dp pulls a suspicious size attribute warning